# SQL Server Management Studio when creating check constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use SSMS and want to create a check constraint for a table.

So I right click on constraint node and select New constraint, and I set the expression to `Mycolumn > 5`

Then I click on close.

After this I do not see this new check constraint added under constraint node. I refresh but still do not see it.

Then I add a row with `MyColumn = 2` - nothing happens.

What am I missing here? I use SQL Server 2008.

I need an answer for this using SSMS, I know the answer using T-SQL.

============================================================

Screenshots:

Table definition

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or something?

Comment: You have to refresh the object explorer. Honestly, you should be creating constraints in code instead of SSMS.

Comment: Is it possible that existing data does not comply with this check constraint?

Comment: Very good question. I truncated the table. Tried to add an invalid row and was able to add it. The big question is "is a check constraint supposed to shows under constraint node in SSMS?

Comment: I did a refresh and I still don't see the constraint.

Comment: You truncated the table, *re-created* the check constraint, and then tried to add a row with a column of 5 or less, and it allowed you to do so?

Comment: Yes and I "could not see the constraint " Then I ran  'ALTER TABLE dbo.abc ADD CONSTRAINT CK_number
    CHECK (test >= 10)' Now I can see the constraint. I'm being convinced this is a SSMS bug. Can any of you please test this if you have SSMS (2012) ?

Comment: OK - I'm not a user of this product so i'm not familiar with its behavior. I'm assuming JChao's answer is what you'd need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you noticed when you click "new constraint" it opens up a tab for the table.

After you click close on the check constraints screen you still need to save the table. You can do this by closing the table window or ctrl + s. It will ask you if you want to save. Say "yes".

Comment: haha I knew there was an easy solution to this. To me this is a SSMS flaw as it assumes user has common sense to close the table.

Comment: @SNash Yeah its confusing because it actually opens up the table editor when you click new constraint. So you can edit various parts of the table and then you have to save.